# Why would this work on one site but not another?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, output-buffering

I'm using this js inside of php to show file names as they're iterated through. I have this working perfectly on 6 different websites all of them have the same exact code (WordPress Plugin). But, on another, the html isn't updated until the php has completed.  There's 4 of these sites on the same shared host so the server settings for the one where it doesn't work should be identical to the ones where it does.  It's like the ob isn't starting or flushing.

```
    add_action('init', array($this, 'Do_output_buffer'));

    function Do_output_buffer() {
        ob_start();
    }
```

```
   echo "<script>
      const element = document.querySelector('#filefind');
      </script>";
   @ob_flush();
   @flush();
```

```
   echo "<script>
        element.innerHTML = `<div>" . $value . "</div>`;
        </script>";
   @ob_flush();
   @flush();
```

Thanks!

*edit* 
Per request

````
        $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);        
        foreach ($objects as $filename => $value) {
             echo "<script>element.innerHTML = `<div>" . $filename . "</div>`;  
             </script>";
             @ob_flush();
             @flush();
        }

    ```
````

Comment: Can you show us in context how your actually using this? Is there also a reason you are suppressing error messages on `ob_flush()` and `flush()`

Comment: Ok, added some code to give an example of what I'm doing. Basically iterating through the entire directory tree and displaying the file name in, hopefully, the same location and as it's iterated through.  Why the suppression?  Good question.  I SUCK at JS and this was a code example I found that worked so I left it as is.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things going on with what you're trying to `echo` out.

1. The backticks in the echo might be causing an issue
2. The end `</script>` isn't getting echoed out.

I would change the code to this:

```
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);        
foreach ($objects as $filename => $value) {
     // Enclose the echo in single quotes and use double quotes for the actual JS.
     echo '<script>element.innerHTML = "<div>' . $filename . '</div>";</script>';    
     // Remove the error suppression so you can actual see errors.
     ob_flush();
     flush();
}
```

I'm also not sure how your main plugin works with the `Do_output_buffer()` function - since it's called on `init` it's going to buffer until it gets flushed...after the first `foreach` - then the buffer *might* be rendered useless. If that's the case, you could open the buffer in each iteration:

```
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);        
foreach ($objects as $filename => $value) {
     // Start the buffer here.
     ob_start();
     // Enclose the echo in single quotes and use double quotes for the actual JS.
     echo '<script>element.innerHTML = "<div>' . $filename . '</div>";</script>';    
     // Remove the error suppression so you can actual see errors.
     // Flush the buffer.
     ob_flush();
     flush();
     // repeat
    }
```

Comment: Ok, gave it a try with the ob_start() and suppression off.  No errors and same problem. One site doesn't show the output till the html is finished. The other sites display the file names as they are looped through.

This is why I suck at JS.  Over here, it works. Over there, it doesn't so I never know if I've got my code right or not.

Comment: Ok, just did a test and ran ob_get_status(true) on the working an non-working site and found the problem. Now I just got to figure out how to fix it.  On the working site, the var_dump showed one buffer.  On the non-working site, it showed two buffers, the first was empty and the second had content. I apparently need to figure out a way to track which buffer my plugin is using.

Comment: Yeah, if you are getting two buffers, there is definitely something weird. Since I don't have access to the plugin, it seems like opening the buffer in the `init` hook is a bad idea. `init` basically runs every time the plugin is first called. If you have another plugin or something that is flushing the output buffer, you may be getting conflicting buffers. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I checked that.  Before I ran the init, there were 0 buffers.  After the init, 1 buffer.  By the time the code got to my menu, there were 2 buffers and the init was the only place where I was doing an ob_start and it definitely wasn't doing the init twice. So, the only conclusion I could draw was that something else started one.  My solution probably isn't the best. I would imagine some method with ob_get_level() would be better but, eh. it works.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, the problem was some other plugin or theme on that one site was creating an extra output buffer and wasn't clearing it out when done.  When I var_dumped the ob_get_status(true) I saw this.

```
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "default output handler"
    ["type"]=>
    int(0)
    ["flags"]=>
    int(112)
    ["level"]=>
    int(0)
    ["chunk_size"]=>
    int(0)
    ["buffer_size"]=>
    int(16384)
    ["buffer_used"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "default output handler"
    ["type"]=>
    int(0)
    ["flags"]=>
    int(112)
    ["level"]=>
    int(1)
    ["chunk_size"]=>
    int(0)
    ["buffer_size"]=>
    int(32768)
    ["buffer_used"]=>
    int(28778)
  }
}
```

This meant that every flush or ob_flush I was sending was apparently flushing the wrong buffer and outputting nothing.  So, the solution I came up with was to check before I started sending output to see how many buffers there were.  If there was more than one, I flushed and closed all of the buffers except one. And, amazingly, it started working.

Here's the hacky code I quickly came up with:

````
```
        $buffers = ob_get_status(true);

        //shows the array of how many buffers are active.
        //echo '<pre>';
        //echo 'Buffer Count: '. count($buffers).'<br>';
        //var_dump(ob_get_status(true));
        //echo '</pre>';

        if (count($buffers) > 1) {
            for ($i=0;$i<count($buffers)-1;$i++) {
                ob_end_flush();
            }
        }
```
````

Thanks @disinfor for the replies and helping me sound this out.